# package-lock.json is breaking my build

Tags: npm, npm-install, node-modules, package-lock.json

As part of my CI, build script is running `npm install` every time after it checkouts latest code from git repo. Since couple of days ago my build started to fail because of missing module, with error message:

```
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'cuint'
```

When I looked a bit into it I realized that from some point `npm install` command has started to behave differently and my `package-lock.json` file was updated in a way that it does not require this `cuint` module any longer.
Here is screenshot of a part of my `package-lock.json` before and after the `npm install` command:

[image]

Part which confuses me the most is how come that the same package `xxhashjs` with the same version `0.2.1` before required `cuint` module and now it doesn't, allegedly. Isn't that breaking the whole point of having locked versions?

Any idea on how to deal with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Were you using the same npm versions in both scenarios?

Comment: @KaushikTD, yes I was ... anyhow I moved to newer version of xxhashjs which correctly requires cuint, so this got fixed. But I haven't figured this problem